# How can I make Android Disa work with Windows Whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, windows

I have the app Disa which has all the messaging services, including SMS and Whatsapp, nicely integrated into one application.

However, I want to get my messages on windows as well. If you use the official Windows client for Whatsapp, you have to verify it using the official Android Whatsapp on your phone.

You can't use Disa *and* official Whatsapp for the same number at the same time, and if you switch from the official app to Disa, Windows Whatsapp will stop working.

How can I fix it so Whatsapp windows will work, and Whatsapp will still be activated for Disa?

Coming at this from another angle, if you know a Windows client that will gel with Disa, let me know [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37122/whatsapp-client-for-windows-7-which-doesnt-need-official-whatsapp-on-phone).

Comment: Been looking for the same feature for a while, but seems the developers haven't gotten their hands onto that feature as well. Perhaps in the near future, there will a "disa version" of WhatsApp web. If there is something new be welcome to answer your own question :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you were looking for a "Disa Web" feature like Whatsapp Web. Unfortunately as of now the feature is not yet availble.

According to Disa Unified Messenger Community forums (moderator);

> This feature is not yet available . The third party plugin developer
>   hasn't added this feature yet. But the Disa team has plans for making
>   a web version in the future. This will work with every plugin.

Currently the developers are working full time on telegram plugin and bug fixes.

So as of now you'll have to stick either Disa whatsapp plugin or Official whatsapp client (with web version) - you can't mix them both.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found, I am just checking it out.  Give it a try!

https://www.bluestacks.com/download.html?utm_campaign=homepage-dl-button-en

In order to run Disa on your computer or laptop you will need to download and install BlueStacks Android Emulator by clicking here.

Credits:

https://www.techforpc.com/disa-for-pc-windows-7-8-10-mac-laptop-free-download/

while you are there do check out the email integrator from Disa for PC from

http://disa.im/faq.html

Click on send an email and add all your email accounts from different service providers and you should be able to have one common inbox or 'combined mailbox'